# When was the Game Boy Pocket released in Europe?

Tags: game-boy

You'd think this would be the simplest thing in the world to find out, but Wikipedia and all other sources just mention the USA and Japan release dates -- not the European one. I have no idea why because I know for a 100% fact that they did release the Game Boy **Pocket** here.

Wikipedia doesn't even have a dedicated article for it -- it's part of the general Game Boy article.

It probably was sometime in 1996, but I need the exact date.

Comment: Could the European release date be included in the PAL release date?

Comment: @UncleBod Yes, but even that info was lacking wherever I looked?

Answer (score 3):

The Spanish Wikipedia has a [dedicated Gameboy Pocket](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Pocket) article, giving a European release date of March 1997.

Comment: And the Swedish Wikipedia article about Game Boy Pocket says it was released in Sweden 14th November 1996.